# Why Magento send newsletter emails to all subscribers one time, not every minute

Tags: email, magento, cron, newsletter

Magento newsletter cron job work sending newsletter mail only one time. But "cron_schedule" table update newsletter records with success status every minute. I want to send newsletter email by scheduled time. How can i fix it? Please guide me...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

1. Choose the correct timezone to solve the timing issue as follow.

Stores-> Configuration -> General -> General -> Locale Options -> Timezone

2. You have to set Cronjob to send the newsletter automatically at a scheduled time or you can manually run this command to run cron manually:

php bin/magento cron:run

For more details please visit the below link: https://www.mageworx.com/wiki/cat/magento-2-email-newsletter/

Note: I had to install the SMTP extension (https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/) to send emails from my local host.